# What does Contract="*" mean?

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I came across the [following code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee816859%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
<client>
   <!--set up the destination endpoints-->
   <endpoint name="CalcEndpoint1"
          address="net.tcp://localhost:9090/servicemodelsamples/service/"
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          contract="*" />

   <endpoint name="CalcEndpoint2"
          address="net.tcp://localhost:8080/servicemodelsamples/service/"
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          contract="*" />
</client>
```

1. What does `contract="*"`mean?
2. Doesn't every WCF Client or service have to have the contract specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used for routing in a service.  The asterisk signifies to match any contract that comes in. 
I've used it as a gateway when on VPN to get to specific services behind a firewall.  I send the request to the router service, which checks the contract, and routes it to the actual service behind  the firewall.

Something like this example here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/423064/Getting-Started-with-WCF-4-0-Routing-Service)

Answer (score 0):

WCF Service should have at least a single contract defined.

Contract string(at the endpoint level) indicates a contract for an endpoint.
If your service implementation implements only a single contract, then you can set it to empty string and Default contract is used.

Comment: That's what I thought. So how you explain the code above and the "*"? There is no contract in the code above.

Comment: Best explanation I could find is that asterisk is used disabling SOAP Action header checks. Here is the link of original article: http://shishkin.wordpress.com/2007/03/21/wcf-actions-asterisk-and-metadata/